# How do I find out if a user actually shared my content?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-twitter

I know that I can use an intent to initialize normal sharing, I don't know if it's possible to tell if the user actually completed the share.  Is there a way to get a callback on the share method?  If not, can I at least know if the user opened up another app, regardless of what they did or did not post (maybe using a custom chooser)?

If it comes down to separate implementations for each possible method of sharing, I know that for facebook I can use FacebookDialog.getNativeDialogCompletionGesture() to find out if the share succeeded. Is there a similar call in any Twitter or SMS API?